# Mobile Game: Google Play no supported dev country and capitalization alternatives (no policies violation or suspicious behavior)?

Tags: android, mobile, google-play, monetization, in-app-purchase

If my country is listed as not supported as a developer country (for payments), this mean developer can upload app but no make any money with it. If I understood correctly, not even in app ads are allowed (I have my doubts about ads because It has no sense they aren't allowed).

Is there any mean, friendly with Google policies, to monetize the app?

For example:

- Desktop version is free to play. Optional content requires a payment.
- Mobile version is free to play. Optional content requires you to log in with same account you used to purchase it on desktop. No ads and no in-app purchase in mobile version.

Is the above scenario OK? Which are the alternatives?

Notes:

To me, no ads has no sense. After reading Developer Console documentation I assumed that ads are OK but after doing some research It turns on that many people thinks that ads are not OK.

Comment: Which country?.

Comment: @SP. It isn't relevant. Any country with a red cross in the Google Merchant column: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/table/3539140

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your country is marked red crossed in merchant account then you are not allowed to do any kind of direct bank transaction. Example: In-app purchase of any kind, sell premium app, Ad remove purchase etc. These kinds of transactions use direct bank account which is known as merchant account.

Ads are alright as the transactions are done via a simple ad ID or third party service. This is allowed in every country in that list.

So you will have to depend on only Ads revenue if you publish your apps from your country.

As an alternative, you can establish your company's legal entity in another country where you will have full app store privileges and publish apps from there when you are developing in your country. May need a little legal consultation. Estonian e-residency allows full remote control over your company as well as banking and other stuff.

[My reddit thread on similar case and findings.](https://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev/comments/4mrtn5/game_publishing_business_foreign_authentic_remote/?st=it1x58t6&sh=19ff0b75)

Comment: OK. Thank you for clarifying that ads are OK. Your reddit thread is very interesting, sadly I don't think I can do that but I will look If something similar can be done here (of course, flying to another country to collect id card isn't an option for me).